# Angular causes “10 $digest iterations reached” in IE

Tags: angularjs, internet-explorer

I am creating a angular application, I am having 2 pages in my app, I have a back button in my 2nd page which internally calls window.location to redirect to 1st page, first time if we click back button it is redirecting properly to my 1st page, second time from 2nd page if we click back button I am getting the below error, and my application is struck, I am not able to do any thing further, I don't know why it is not working for the second time. Please help me to fix this issue.

```
   Error: [$rootScope:infdig] 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!
Watchers fired in the last 5 iterations:
at $digest (/bower_components/angular/angular.js:11847:13)
   at $apply (/bower_components/angular/angular.js:12061:13)
   at Anonymous function (/bower_components/angular/angular.js:13594:25)
   at completeOutstandingRequest (/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4111:7)
   at Anonymous function (/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4418:7) 
SCRIPT5022: [$rootScope:infdig] 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!
```

this issue is occurring only in IE.

Comment: Provide some code or plunker/fiddle.

Comment: Please create fiddle or post your app.js code and html

Comment: I am having 20+ htmls and 50+ js files. created lot of service, filters, directives, not able to find which file is causing this issue.